# Multipart-form (image,parameters) Post request with Alamofire in swift

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

I have a `Dictionary<String,<Array<Dictiolnary<String,String>>>>`
With a `UIImage` object.

How to upload an image with a parameter that has a dictionary with the value of an array and the array has also a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse the complete dictionary, convert the value of each key on the `Data` and append it with the request body.